# Parameterize @BeforeMethod method in TestNG

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider, parameterized-tests

I have a base test class for my tests which does the initialisation work before each test.

Here is the code

```
public class BaseTestParameters {

  MyObj myObj;

  @DataProvider(name = "apiType")   
  public static Object[][] createData() {

     return new Object[][] {{"type", "1"},{"type","2"}};   
  } 

  @BeforeMethod()   
  @Factory(dataProvider = "apiType")   
  public void setup(String type,String param) throws Exception {

     myObj = createMyObject(param);

  }
}
```

All my test classes extend this base class and they use the `myObj` for the tests.

`myObj` has two different ways of creation (depending on param).
All the tests will run twice . One with each way of constituting `myObj`.

How do I enable this scenario ?
Using `@Factory` annotation means I need to return `Object[]` from that method, but I don't have to return any test classes from that method.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `@Parameters` annotation, but you have to specify values in `testng,xml` it means you have to have separate `testng.xml` for each set of parameters.

Here is example:

**AppTest.java**

```
public class AppTest {
    @Parameters({"par1", "par2"})
    @BeforeMethod()
    public void setUp(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println("a = [" + a + "], b = [" + b + "]");
    }

    @Test
    public void testApp() {
    }
}
```

**testng.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >

    <test name="Run1" >
        <parameter name="par1"  value="val"/>
        <parameter name="par2"  value="anotherval"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="dummy.java" />
        </packages>
    </test>

    <test name="Run2" >
        <parameter name="par1"  value="newValue"/>
        <parameter name="par2"  value="yetAnotherVal"/>
        <packages>
            <package name="dummy.java" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: This will just replace par1 and par2 values in setup function. I need testApp to run once with par1 and once with par2. Some kind of iteration over parameters while running the tests.

Comment: @lostintranslation I updated my answer. Now it runs test twice with different values.

Comment: Getting this error - Parameter 'par1' is required by '@Configuration' on method setup but has not been marked '@Optional' or defined. par2 is overwriting par1 when testng is initialising.

Comment: Adding two <test> seems overdo for such a simple use case. Will shift to junit. Testng is not a good choice for such cases.

Comment: How do you run your test? It seems like you didn't use `testng.xml`.

Comment: Yes, `JUnit` support your case way better.

Comment: No. I am using intellij to run my test case. I need to try these parameters for only one test case. Running via xml will run all test cases which I dont want